# If i press right alt this hide, when i press again program shows and hide

Tags: c#, wpf, minimized

```
            if (e.KeyData.ToString().ToUpper() == "RMENU")
            {
                if(alt==2)
                    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    alt = 1;
                else
                    WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                    alt = 2;
            }
```

**If i press right alt this hide, when i press again program shows and hide**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (e.KeyData.ToString().ToUpper() == "RMENU")
    {
        if (alt == 2)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            alt = 1;
        }
        else if (alt == 1)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            alt = 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: need only add curly brace -.-

Comment: hope u have a nice day!